# Backbone.js - Collection is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I'm trying to learn backbone.js but the I'm stuck on fetching the json and adding to the collection.The collection is undefined and I don't know why.
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
        //model
        window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend();

        window.WineCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
            url: "http://localhost/bootstrap/json.php",
            model: Wine
        });


        //views
        window.WineItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($("#wine-item-template").html()),
            tagName: 'li',
            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'ul',
            initialize: function() {
                this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);

            },
            render: function() {

                _.each(this.model.models, function(wine) {
                    $(this.el).append(new WineItemView({
                        model: wine
                    }).render().el);
                }, this);
                return this;
            }
        });


        window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($('#wine-template').html()),
            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });
        //Router
        window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'wines/:id': "wineDetails"
            },
            home: function() {
                this.wineList = new WineCollection();

                this.wineListV = new WineListView({
                    model: this.wineList
                });
                this.wineList.fetch({success: function(){
                    console.log(this.wineList.models); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
                }});
                console.log(this.wineListV);

                $("#winelist").html(this.wineListV.render().el);
            },
            wineDetails: function(id) {
                this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
                console.log(id);
                this.wineView = new WineView({
                    model: this.wine
                });
                $("#container").empty().html(this.wineView.render().el);
            }
        });


    })(jQuery);

    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

json.php returns:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Wine 1",
      "price":"100",
      "status":"available"
   },
   {
      "name":"Wine 1",
      "price":"100",
      "status":"available"
   },
   {
      "name":"Wine 1",
      "price":"100",
      "status":"available"
   }
]
```

I'm testing this on my localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
            model: Wine,
            url: "wine.json"

        });
```

to

```
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Wine,
            url: "wine.json"

        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You made a silly typo:

```
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Model.extend
```

should be

```
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend
```

Note that by convention your `WineListView` class should use this.collection to refer to an instance of `WineCollection` and Backbone collection objects provide the underscore iteration methods so instead of

```
.each(this.model.models, function(wine) {
```

do

```
this.collection.each(function (wineModel) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :) this is your 1st questoin so let me make it memorable one. when you say collection is `undefined` you could have provided us the Line number(or highlighted it) so that it would be easy to debug. inside `initialize` method you have to put `_.bindAll(this)` in the case you wanted to reference the object that you wanted to( defaults to `window` object ) instead of below do #1

```
 _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
     $(this.el).append(new WineItemView({
         model: wine
     }).render().el);
 }, this);
```

#### 1

```
 this.model.each(function (wine) {
     $(this.el).append(new WineItemView({
         model: wine
     }).render().el);
 }, this);
```

try this too

```
 window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
     tagName: 'ul',
     initialize: function () {
         _.bindAll(this);
         this.model.on('reset', this.render);
     },
     render: function () {
         #1
     }
 });
```

Just in case you got lost here is a copy of the code http://jsbin.com/axixir/edit#javascript

Comment: Thanks for helping out.I'm getting `this.model.each is not a function` on line 37.Also `this.wineList is undefined` on line 67

Comment: @SebastianLucaciu sorry it is not each it is `forEach`

Comment: `_.each(list, iterator, [context]) Alias: forEach` , so I think _.each should have worked.The problem is that `this.model.models` is undefined